Eclipse Window Builder can't find Root Method and does not display anything. How do I fix this?
Every time I open the Design tab to view my GUI an error message states that there are "no root methods". I have cleaned the project, checked that all files associated with Window Builder are up to date, and have deleted the project and reuploaded it to Eclipse only to get the same message every time. When I run the code it produces the correct output, but I cannot see it in the Design tab or use any of the tools from that tab. I have uploaded a screenshot of the error message.
Update:
This does not seem to be a code issue, as when I compile the project in a remote access version of Eclipse that I have access to it allows me to view the project in the Design tab and use the tools as well. However, my personal IDE is still having issues.
The parser can't find any root method(s) (entry points for parsing). The parser starts parsing from known method(s) for each GUI toolkit. For example, for Swing it starts from the constructor of a JPanel or JFrame. If the currently parsed class is not a subclass of a Swing component, the parser will try to find a main(java.lang.String[]) method. If it also does not exist, this exception will be shown. Usually this means that you are trying to parse something not supported by WindowBuilder (for example, a non-GUI compilation unit).
The error message provided within the Design tab is below:
Note that even if WindowBuilder can't recognize your code pattern automatically, sometimes you can still teach WindowBuilder to work with it by providing a @wbp.parser.entryPoint JavaDoc hint. For example:
    public class MyClass {
        /**
         * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
         */
        public void someNonStandardEntryPoint() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            ...;
        }
    }


Your initial question in the staging ground was quite different. Based on your screenshot which you removed, please try the following: set the cursor somewhere into class TopDestinationListFrame, right-click and choose Refactor > Move Type to New File and then try to open the new created file TopDestinationListFrame.java with WindowBuilder. By doing so, the comment with @wbp.parser.entryPoint should not be needed anymore. Please tell whether this works for you for your actual problem.

Unfortunately, this does not work. The same error message is displayed in the Design window. Could this happen if the file uses an older Java version than my IDE?

Actually, after reviewing my question and seeing the added explanation about how parsing is handled, I think there may be a Swing subclass, or GUI toolkit, that I have access to within the remote environment's IDE that I do not have on my own.

Please provide a complete minimal reproducible example. Have you managed to get rid of the anti-pattern in your code? Your comments are unclear to me and give the impression that you are heading in the wrong direction (so far, you have not shown anything that make sense to be edited in WindowBuilder).
